# to print the python script output in excel

Tags: python

i want to print the output of python script in excelfile. i tried this code  but it reads each line from the selected input file and then writes it to a new excel file called output.xls? thank you

```
 import xlwt
 from Tkinter import *            
 from tkFileDialog   import askopenfilename      

 def callback():
     filename = askopenfilename()
     wb = xlwt.Workbook()
     ws0 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet1')

     with open(filename, 'r') as f:
         for i, line in enumerate(f):
             ws0.write(i, 0, line.strip())
     wb.save('output.xls')

 errmsg = 'Error!'
 a = Button(text='click me', command=callback)
 a.pack()
 mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by `print the output of python script in excelfile`? And how is the above **not** what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the opposite of what you're doing - eg, reading the rows from an excel file, then you can work with this (which takes your generated file as per your code as input)

```
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('output.xls')
ws = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
for rowno in xrange(ws.nrows):
    print ws.row_values(rowno)
```

Comment: No I wrote a simple script to  check the divison by 0 used in code i.e., if divison by 0 is used it will print that line no..so i want to dump that output from python shell to excel please help me

Comment: @user1763020 It's still difficult to understand what you mean - are you not just after instead of writing all rows, only writing those where your divide by zero condition occurs?

Comment: thank you..take example of simple code import linecache
cnt=1
de = '#define'
mn = 'MODULE'
while cnt!=1500:
   dat=linecache.getline('opensmefile', cnt)
   if(dat.count(mn!=0)):
      print cnt
cnt=cnt+1....i want this script output in excel

Answer (score 0):

```
import xlwt

x = (("a",1),("b",2),("c",3))

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet("test")
for i, row in enumerate(x):
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
        ws.write(i, j, col)
wb.save("sample.xls")
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot..is der any way to dump the Output of a python script to excel file i mean i should get my script output in excel..to do this should i add anything to my script